# Swift closure syntax using Shark Food Mute Switch?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, mute

I am having trouble with swift closure syntax. I am trying to check the mute switch using Sharkfood which you can see here: http://sharkfood.com/content/Developers/content/Sound%20Switch/

The Block I'm trying to call is shown below.

```
typedef void(^SharkfoodMuteSwitchDetectorBlock)(BOOL silent);
```

This is how I'm trying to call it but it isn't working. I've tried a ton of different ways and I know I'm missing something little since I'm new to swift. The error I'm getting is:

> '(Bool) -> Void' is not convertible to 'Bool'

On the first line of this code:

```
muteDetector.silentNotify({
    (silent: Bool) -> Void in
    println("this")
    println("worked")
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you successfully implement the Sound Switch library in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Never used that library, but looking at the documentation linked in your question I notice that `silentNotify` is a property:

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) SharkfoodMuteSwitchDetectorBlock silentNotify;
```

containing the block, so the error stating that a BOOL is expected makes sense.

Instead with your code you are probably trying to call this method:

```
-(void)setSilentNotify:(SharkfoodMuteSwitchDetectorBlock)silentNotify{
    _silentNotify = [silentNotify copy];
    self.forceEmit = YES;
}
```

I don't know which of the 2 you are attempting to do - if you want to call the block, then you have to just provide a bool:

```
muteDetector.silentNotify(true)
```

if instead you want to register a new block (closure), then you have to use:

```
muteDetector.setSilentNotify({
    (silent: Bool) -> Void in
    println("this")
    println("worked")
})
```

Comment: The line of code I'm trying to replicate in their examples is below:
 self.detector.silentNotify = ^(BOOL silent){
            [sself.stateLabel setText:silent?@"ON":@"OFF"];
        };

Comment: Then I think you should use the last piece of code in my answer, the one using `setSilentNotify` - although I think you can also assign the closure directly to the `silentNotify` property (but the method also sets a `forceEmit` property, and I ignore what is that for)